# Right Differentiability of $\|f(x)\|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

**Problem:** Let $E$ be a normed space, and $f:[a,b]\to E$ be continuous.
Define $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ by $g(x)=\|f(x)\|$.
Prove that if $f'_{+}(t_0)$ exists for some $t\in[a,b)$, then so does $g'_{+}(t_0)$,
and moreover
$$|g'_{+}(t_0)|\leq \|f'_{+}(t_0)\|.$$

**What I have done:**
I couldn't prove the existence of $g'_{+}(x)$, however assume it exists I can prove
the inequality as follows:
For $h>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
g(t_0+h)-g(t_0)
&=\|f(t_0+h)-f(t_0)+f(t_0)\|-\|f(t_0)\|\\
&\leq \|f(t_0+h)-f(t_0)\|
\end{align*}
Since $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous, and by assumption $g'_{+}(t_0)$ exists, we obtain that
$g'_+(t_0)\leq \|f'_+(t_0)\|.$
Similar argument yields $-g'_+(t_0)\leq \|f'_+(t_0)\|$. Thus we obtain the desired inequality.

**Need Help:** How to prove $g'_+(t_0)$ exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}, e_1,e_2 \in E$, then the map $\phi:[a,b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(x) = \|e_1+xe_2\| $ is convex and hence has a right derivative at any point in $[a,b)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable)).

Let $\gamma = f_+'(x)$, $r(h) = f(x+h)-f(x)-h\gamma$ and suppose $h>0$ (and $x+h \le b$).

Note that
$\|f(x+h)\| = \|f(x)+h\gamma + r(h) \| $ satisfies

$\|f(x)+h\gamma \| + \| r(h) \| \ge \|f(x+h)\|  $ and
$\|f(x+h)\| \ge \|f(x)+h\gamma\| - \|r(h) \| $.

By subtracting $\|f(x)\|$ and dividing both sides by $h$ and letting $h \downarrow 0$ we get
$\lim_{h \downarrow 0} {\|f(x)+h\gamma \| - \|f(x)\| \over h} = 
\lim_{h \downarrow 0} {\|f(x+h) \| - \|f(x)\| \over h}$ (recall that $\phi$ defined above has a right derivative). In particular, $g_+'(x)$ exists.

Comment: Nice solution. As a small remark, it looks like there should be $-h\gamma$ in the $r(h)$ term, not $+h\gamma$.

Comment: @DeanMiller Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat. I totally get it now. In our case we let $\phi(t)=\|f(x)+t\gamma\|$ and argue that $\phi'_+(0)$ exists.

Comment: @aaravos Yes, that is the crux of the argument.